# ASP.NET 5 - Reference a NuGet package dynamically

Tags: nuget, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET 5 (MVC 6) web application. When I deploy it into the IIS in some folder I can see all NuGet packages (referenced from the `project.json` file, `dependencies` section) were copied into the folder `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp\approot\packages`.

Is there any way to add a reference to a NuGet package dynamically ? Something like adding the package manually into this `..\approot\packages` folder and somehow telling the application to load it.

I realized that only the packages from the `project.json` file (`dependencies` section) are loaded and even if the NuGet package is in this folder `..\approot\packages` it is not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that's not supported out of the box. Probably you could come up with some hacky unsupported way of doing it by duplicating code from DNX but it is really not recommended.

If you manage to do it, be aware that you might break some scenarios. The first that comes to my mind is servicing because the servicing breadcrumbs will not be written on disk at the right time. This could be a big security vulnerability.

Second, it would be tricky to load correctly all the new package's dependencies because you need to look at what DNX already loaded and maybe reuse some of them. I'm not 100% sure that we expose all that data.

Also, here's another thing to consider if you manage to load NuGet packages dynamically: what happens to that NuGet package's dependencies? If they are not available, do you go and download them? If yes, from where?